# Is a List Model in an MVVVM app for shared lists feasible?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, model

I have an app with a great many dropdown lists that should remain synchronised between windows. I.e. if a user adds e.g. a new Department, all open forms with Department dropdowns must have the new department as well.

My first thoughts for this is a List Model, from which view models pull their lists. All are ObservableCollections, so the view models subscribe to the list model, wich subscribes to the viewmodels for list changes, and incorporates them.

Or am I building a house of spaghetti here?

Another requirement (these aren't mine) is that list changes by one user, common with other users only through the database, must propagate to other users. I can only think of a broadcast message sent by the list model that is the origin of the change.

Comment: How do users get data? Are they connecting straight to the db or going through a web service?

Comment: @ChrisO Connecting straight to the DB.

Comment: Assuming you're using mssql, you can use the sql server service broker through the SqlDependency class (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency(v=vs.110).aspx) You give it a query, and when the results of that query would have changed (someone else adds a row), you get an event notification in your app so that everyone knows to requery and pick up the new data.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution seems solid. I'd have a `MainWindowViewModel` with your `ObservableCollection<Department>`. When you create a new window, you can pass the reference to the `ObservableCollection` from the `MainWindowViewModel` to the constructor of your new window's view model. This way, adding new departments will automatically sync to every windows regardless of where it's added.

Comment: Probably a bit easier to pass a reference to the `MainWindowViewModel` and let the new window pick and choose itself, but thanks for the affirmation.

Comment: Honestly, that is an option but having tried both ways, I'm not a big fan. I'd rather just expose the minimum information that the child view models need. I find it less confusing that way.